# Declaring computed properties in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

Trying to declare a simple property in Swift which returns a string but the following code looks like is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
var baseURL :String? = {

              return nil

    }
```

Comment: Remove the `=`.

Comment: Thanks works now! :)